# Trouble connecting to SQL when publishing application to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, tcp

The application loads, but when the application tries to make the connection to SQL it takes a while to load then returns an error.  When testing the connection properties using a DataLink (.udl file) it is successful.  The application also runs fine on my local machine.  I have searched everywhere and the settings are good, the network admin verified the firewalls and everything is set up correct.  What am I missing?

I notice it mentions Name Pipes in the error, however, shouldn't this make it TCP?

```
SQLConnectionString.NetworkLibrary = "dbmssocn";
```

This is my method for the connection string:

```
public string GetReachoutConnectionString()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder SQLConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        SQLConnectionString.TypeSystemVersion = "Latest";
        SQLConnectionString.NetworkLibrary = "dbmssocn";
        SQLConnectionString.DataSource = "10.10.xxx.xx,1433";
        SQLConnectionString.InitialCatalog = "cat";
        SQLConnectionString.UserID = "xxx";
        SQLConnectionString.Password = "xxx";
        SQLConnectionString.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        SQLConnectionString.ApplicationName = "Website";

        return SQLConnectionString.ConnectionString;
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The
>   network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +1394
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1120
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +964
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +114
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1631
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +267
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +211
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +393    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +177
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +182
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable) +123
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +2964
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +369 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +43
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +139 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +107
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +204
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +204
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +204
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +204
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +204
>   System.Web.UI.d__249.MoveNext() +1400
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +13847892
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +32
>   System.Web.UI.d__523.MoveNext() +9283

Comment: maybe the remote server does not support `NamePipes` can you connect to it using the actual sqlserver db name etc.. take a look at [Connection Strings Sql Server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: I don't want to use name pipes.  Why does it think I am trying to?  I am trying to connect using tcp.  I have already checked and they are both enabled.

Comment: because you coded it to look for ip address / namepipes here in this line `SQLConnectionString.DataSource = "10.10.xxx.xx,1433";` read the link I posted in my previous comment on how to configure connection strings in C# using Sql Server..

Comment: I looked at the page you sent me and everything looks correct according to that site.  I am using 'Network Library=DBMSSOCN' to designate it as tcp.   On that website it says, "DBMSSOCN=TCP/IP is how to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes."

Comment: are you in charge of administering the remote server..? if not then get with a dba and have them confirm if TcpIp/NamedPipes is support as well as turned on.. sounds like you're going to have to change your code.. it's not difficult

Comment: I have gotten with them and they are turned on.  What are you saying is the problem with my code?  It works on my local machine.  What do I need to change?

Comment: Are you able to connect your SQL server with the credentials you have ?

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the default port: `,1433` in the datasource string, try removing that. If it still does't work, try using telnet to connect to the ip of the sqlserver on port 1433. if you can't connect, you should get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there was a miscellaneous connection string in the **web.config** file that was causing the program to return that error.  It was automatically added by visual studio when I was testing different methods of connecting.  I deleted it and it worked.  Nothing was wrong with my connection string, it was failing when the next page was loading and trying to use the other connection string that was auto entered.  That's why using the GUI interface can just cause issues sometimes.